# Wordpress - Safest method to define global variables

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, global-variables

I don't know if "global" is the right word, but what I have to do is: define a variable that I can use in many parts of the template.

Example: I have to define a variable that contains the ID of a static page

```
$page_id = 34
```

and I have to use it in different template parts, with functions like

```
get_page_link($page_id)
```

I found many way to do it (PHP define(), in function.php, global, ...) but I ask what is **the most secure**, in your opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either define it in `wp-config` file (which will be accessible among all theme ) or in your `function.php` of your theme directory.

Example: **Function.php**

```
global $blog_pageId;
$blog_pageId = 34;
```

Or just create a small function which return you the id.

```
function get_blog_page_id(){
      return "34";
}
```

Than one can call it as,

```
 $blog_pageId = get_blog_page_id();
```

Comment: Hi Rikesh! sorry but it's not clear. I prefer to not modify the wp-config, then I go for the functions.php method but it doesn't work. what is `$domain`? I've tried also `global $page_id` but nothing.

Comment: @FredK - Sorry updated. Try to declare var like this & than access it in any of your theme file.

Comment: tried `global $page_id; $page_id = 34;` in function.php and `get_page_link($page_id)` in another php file but it doesn't work!

Comment: @FredK - Just before `get_page_link($page_id)` add `global $page_id;`.

Comment: yes! now it works but notice that it works also without the `global $page_id` in functions.php. is it normal? my question was about the most security: is this the most secure way? what do you think about `define('PAGE_ID', 34);`

Comment: @FredK - Yes, it is normal. And what type of security you mean ? Obviously outsider can't access this variable at all. The only one who have code access can able to access it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28971/discussion-between-fred-k-and-rikesh)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use wordpress default functionality like

**global $wpdb;**

on above global variable **$wpdb** is use in all page of wordpress so you can also create your own function and create one global variable which is declare all pages or posts .

Comment: I defined `global $page_id;` in functions.php but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

if you're using pretty permalinks, get_query_var('page_id') won't work.

Instead, get the queried object ID from the global $wp_query:

```
// Since 3.1 - recommended!
$page_object = get_queried_object();
$page_id     = get_queried_object_id();


// "Dirty" pre 3.1
global $wp_query;

$page_object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$page_id     = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
```